# Phonegap microphone stream

Tags: cordova, audio, stream, microphone

Hy!

Is there a possibility to use the microphone to get an audio stream?
The capture API from Phonegap is only able to save the audio file before accessing the data.

I want to analyse the audio stream in real-time and can't find a way to do this.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: you should create a plugin to do that

Comment: I guess to create a plugin, I have to write native code for all platforms (iOS, Android and WP)? I'm completely new in mobile development and can't estimate how much work that would be!

Comment: a lot, but there is no other way

Comment: I'm thinking about changing to Xamarin oder directly to native dev. for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The [phonegap-plugin-media-stream](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-media-stream) plugin exposes your microphone as a WebRTC stream, so you can do any analysis WebRTC supports.